# Conversión entre punteros inteligentes

Tags: c++, c++11

Supongamos que tenemos las siguientes clases:

```
struct A
{
  virtual ~A() = default;
};

struct B : A
{ };
```

Además, tenemos una función factoría que nos devuelve punteros inteligentes genéricos de tipo A:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> FuncionFactoria(int n)
{
  if( n % 2 )
    return std::make_shared<A>();
  else
    return std::make_shared<B>();
}
```

Y, por otro lado, tenemos un par de funciones. Una admite un puntero inteligente de tipo A y la otra un puntero inteligente de tipo B:

```
void FuncionGenerica(std::shared_ptr<A>);
void FuncionEspecifica(std::shared_ptr<B>);
```

¿Cómo se podría realizar una conversión segura entre punteros? Un posible ejemplo de uso:

```
int main()
{
  for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
  {
    std::shared_ptr<A> aSptr = FuncionFactoria(i);
    std::shared_ptr<B> bSptr = /* ¿¿¿??? */
    if( bSptr )
      FuncionEspecifica(bSptr);

    FuncionGenerica(aSptr);
  }
}
```

Notad que los punteros de tipo A deben ser válidos después de la conversión...

Comment: No tengo mucha experiencia con ese tipo de puntero, pero quizas `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<A>(bSptr)` , pero igual el struct precise de un destructor virtual, no puedo aportar nada a su pregunta espero le ayude lo anterior, aunque puede ser que este mal totalmente. Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las herramientas de transformación de punteros inteligentes proveídas por la librería estándar [deberían bastar](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast):

- `std::shared_ptr<T> static_pointer_cast( const std::shared_ptr<U>& r );` el equivalente a [`static_cast`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) con otros tipos de datos.
- `std::shared_ptr<T> dynamic_pointer_cast( const std::shared_ptr<U>& r );` el equivalente a [`dynamic_cast`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) con otros tipos de datos.
- `std::shared_ptr<T> const_pointer_cast( const std::shared_ptr<U>& r );` el equivalente a [`const_cast`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) con otros tipos de datos.
- `std::shared_ptr<T> reinterpret_pointer_cast( const std::shared_ptr<U>& r );` el equivalente a [`reinterpret_cast`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) con otros tipos de datos.

Todas estas converesiones están disponibles a través de la cabecera [`<memory>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory) que, si estás usando punteros inteligentes, deberás haber incluido en algún punto.

Si consultamos la implementación<sup>1</sup> de la conversión de punteros inteligentes, podemos ver que el `std::static_pointer_cast` se comporta de esta manera:

```
template< class T, class U > 
std::shared_ptr<T> static_pointer_cast( const std::shared_ptr<U>& r ) noexcept
{
    auto p = static_cast<typename std::shared_ptr<T>::element_type*>(r.get());
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(r, p);
}
```

Según la [documentación disponible en cppreference](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) está usando el octavo constructor cuyos detalles son:

> Construye un `shared_ptr` que comparte la información de propiedad con `r` pero almacena un puntero `ptr` no auto-gestionado y no relacionado. Incluso si este `shared_ptr` es el último de un grupo en abandonar el ámbito, se llamará el destructor del objeto originalmente auto-gestionado por `r`. Sin embargo, llamar a `get()` siempre devolverá una copia de `ptr`. Es responsabilidad del programador asegurar que `ptr` permanece valido mientras este `shared_ptr` exista.

Por lo que, en tu caso se puede usar `std::static_pointer_cast` en tu código sin afectar a la seguridad del mismo:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> FuncionFactoria(int n)
{
    if( n % 2 )
        return std::make_shared<A>();
    else
        return std::static_pointer_cast<A>(std::make_shared<B>());
        //     ^-------- Transformamos el puntero inteligente
}

int main()
{
    for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
    {
        std::shared_ptr<A> aSptr = FuncionFactoria(i);
        std::shared_ptr<B> bSptr = std::static_pointer_cast<B>(FuncionFactoria(i));
        //                         ^-------- Transformamos el puntero inteligente

        if( bSptr )
            FuncionEspecifica(bSptr);

        FuncionGenerica(aSptr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>La implementación exacta variará entre compiladores, pero el estándar de C++ garantiza que el comportamiento será el mismo independientemente de los detalles de implementación.

Comment: la transformación que haces en `FuncionFactoria` no es necesaria... sin esa transformación se ejecuta la sintaxis move y el objeto `B` se mueve de un puntero intelitente de tipo `B` a otro de tipo `A`.

Comment: Buen punto, pero no estoy 100% seguro. Debo investigar si es completamente seguro.

Comment: Cuando termines tus pesquisas infórmame... por si estoy equivocado :)

Comment: En [`N3235`](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.232.8116&rep=rep1&type=pdf) indican que para conseguir "*una conversión implícita de puntero-a-derivado a puntero-a-base*" [...] "*se requiere un constructor de conversión implícito*", entiendo que esto es porque construir un `shared_ptr<Base>` con un `Deriv *` no es aconsejado... mas sigo buscando.

Comment: Pero eso es cuando estás copiando... si se ejecuta la sintaxis move lo que se invoca es el constructor move del shared_ptr. Mira el constructor (10) de la [documentación](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)